# Annotating arrays to have minItems with Swashbuckle / Swagger

Tags: swashbuckle

Is there a way to annotate my C# code to specify an array is a required parameter and should have at least one item?

It currently shows as optional in Swagger.

I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 1.2.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the parameters in a DTO allows each field to be annotated. In the case of an IEnumerable<> field, it can be annotated with [MinLength(1)], which then carries over to the Swagger.

Answer (score 0):

While this was supported on **Swashbuckle**:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/search?q=minItems

It does not seem to be the case on **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore**

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/search?q=minItems

Your only option is to request it as a new feature, and hopefully they will add it soon:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/new